# removing a beta test (testflight) app on an iphone

Tags: ios, uninstallation, testflight

A colleague of mine has installed a beta app of mine a year ago on his iphone with the use of testflight. Now he cannot delete the app anymore.
The normal move of the icon for deinstallation is simply ignored.

How to delete/uninstall an app after testing?

Comment: What is wrong with this question ? Tell me, when you rate. I can't delete the app, which I have developed.

Comment: Agree with you @mcfly

Comment: @mcfly soft Are you want to delete app from test flight app or from iPhone device.

Comment: If you want to delete from device long press on app icon, it will show x option on app icon. Now click on that app will be deleted automatically. If you want to delete app from test flight remove that user id from your account for that app.

Comment: @mcflysoft What happens if you go to Settings->General->iPhone Storage -><The App you want to delete> (It takes a little while to show all the apps in that list) Then hit "Delete App" button?

Comment: Thanks. I will try. Have to meet the colleague.

Answer (score 1):

I'm an React Native dev who's more used to Android, so I also had trouble with this.

Turns out I was deep pressing (force pressing?) the icon instead of long pressing. You have to make sure you're only pressing lightly in order to make the 'x' icon appear, otherwise you get a menu of options like 'Send Feedback'.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly going off of guess work but will explain as best as I can.

I assume that when you launched the app you did so via iTunes Connect and inside the TestFlight tab?

If so then the TestFlight build should have an expiration date next to it of when the app will stop working. If that doesn't exist the other thing to check is the 'All Testers'tab, move the mouse of the right hand side of the person's name and remove them. That might force the app to delete.

Short of that, the only other thing I can suggest is to meet with the client and try and press and hold on the app and see what happens. You could also go onto the TestFlight app on their device and see what the information says in there.

I hope that helps!